# Scientifc Linux 6, fresh install, does not have a ifcfg-ethX

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, scientific-linux

I installed SL6 few days ago, then I installed the required packages for KVM, however when I tried to modify the ifcfg-ethX file in order to add a bridged connection, I found out that it does not exist at all, I only have the one for the loop back interface.
I looked for the file in the following path /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts, but nothing.
Here you can see what I've got into the network-script folder.

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# ls -a
.            ifdown-ipv6    ifup          ifup-plip    ifup-wireless
..           ifdown-isdn    ifup-aliases  ifup-plusb   init.ipv6-global
ifcfg-lo     ifdown-post    ifup-bnep     ifup-post    net.hotplug
ifdown       ifdown-ppp     ifup-eth      ifup-ppp     network-functions
ifdown-bnep  ifdown-routes  ifup-ippp     ifup-routes  network-functions-ipv6
ifdown-eth   ifdown-sit     ifup-ipv6     ifup-sit
ifdown-ippp  ifdown-tunnel  ifup-isdn     ifup-tunnel
```

I really would appreciate any explanation or link to some document, since the red hat 6 documentation said that I should have it. The other odd thing is that I m connected and every thing work.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same Problem under Fedora 16, then i found this: [ifcfg-eth0-missing](http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/1039/ifcfg-eth0-missing)

so i stoped NetworkManager:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
```

and created the interface file myself.Other than that i found nothing helpful.